# How to assign value if login into mysql in shell?

Tags: bash

I want to assign value if login successfully.

```
mysql -u root -ppassword
```

If succeed ,assign x=0 ,else assign x=1.

How to write it in bash?

Comment: Are you simply logging in from the command line, or are you calling the mysql login from within a script?

Comment: calling it ,if call suecceed , assign x=0 ,else assign x=1., not to login in mysql.

Comment: The reason I ask is that generally when called, you are using the form of something similar to `mysql -u user -ppass -Bse "some query"`. In that case you can check the return as Cyrus mentions below, but be aware that a `failed login` or `successful login/failed command` with both return `1` (failure).